# Binding image controls to observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, observablecollection

I am trying to get an ObservableCollection of BitmapSource objects to bind to a bunch of Images on my WPF form and the image never shows...I verified the image is being loaded into the property, but my binding must be incorrect.....how should the binding path be coded?  I used to have each image bound to a bunch of different objects, but a list is a lot better to use so I want to bind them that way......

The textboxes display the ProgramPath property correctly, I just can't get the image sources bound

XAML - Inside a Grid I have a number of textboxes and images next to each other

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="24,2,2,2" Name="TextBoxA" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                          Width="664" >
                    <Binding Path=".[0].ProgramPath" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <local:ExternalProgramValidator/>
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="24,2,2,2" Name="TextBoxB" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="664" >
                    <Binding Path=".[1].ProgramPath" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <local:ExternalProgramValidator/>
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </TextBox>

<Image Height="16   " HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                       Margin="4" Name="ImageA" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"                           
                       Source="{Binding Path=.[0].ProgramImage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                </Image>
                <Image Grid.Row="1" Height="16   " HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                       Margin="4" Name="ImageB" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"
                       Source="{Binding Path=.[0].ProgramImage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Then I have a public class like this

```
public class ExternalProgramsWindowData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private BitmapSource _ExtractPathImage(string fullPath)
    {
        BitmapSource returnedImage = null;

        string pathForImage = string.Empty;
        string[] s = fullPath.Split(new string[] { ".exe" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        if (s[0] != null)
        {
            pathForImage = s[0] + ".exe";
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pathForImage))
        {
            System.Drawing.Icon icon = IconExtractor.GetIcon(pathForImage, true);

            returnedImage = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
                icon.Handle,
               System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty,
                System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }

        return returnedImage;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A
    /// </summary>
    private string _programPath;
    public string ProgramPath
    {
        get { return _programPath; }
        set
        {
            _programPath = value;
            Notify("ProgramPath");
            ProgramImage = _ExtractPathImage(_programPath);
        }
    }

    private BitmapSource _programImage;
    public BitmapSource ProgramImage
    {
        get { return _programImage; }
        set
        {
            _programImage = value;
            Notify("ProgramImage");
        }
    }


    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void Notify(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

In the Main window class I bind the grid to a collection of those class objects

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class ExternalProgramsWindow : Window
{


    public ObservableCollection<ExternalProgramsWindowData> WindowDataList { get; set; }


WindowDataList = new ObservableCollection<ExternalProgramsWindowData>();

        ExternalPrograms_ExternalProgramsGrid.DataContext = WindowDataList;
```

Then I load the collection and and the ProgramPath property is set and it triggers setting the ProgramImage (which gets set to an image correctly, but the window does not display the image)

```
foreach (ExternalProgram program in externalProgramList)
        {
            ExternalProgramsWindowData oExternalProgramsWindowData = new ExternalProgramsWindowData();
            oExternalProgramsWindowData.ProgramPath = program.Path + " " + program.Arguments;


            WindowDataList.Add(oExternalProgramsWindowData);
```

Comment: [Binding errors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx)?

Comment: See updated question with more code......

Comment: You still make no mention of binding errors, also the formatting is now horrible again :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a custom class as an *ObservableCollection through inheriting* from it. In your code above I can't see the link between the oberservable collection and the property you want to bind to.

```
// assuming ExternalProgramsWindowData are your bitmap objects
public class SourceList : ObservableCollection<ExternalProgramsWindowData> {

}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private SourceList mySourceList;

    public SourceList MySourceList {
         get { return mySourceList; }
         set {
             mySourceList = value;
             FirePropertyChanged("MySourceList");
             }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void FirePropertyChanged (string propertyName) {

        if (PropertyChanged != null) {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

Then in the actual Binding you have the following situation:

Source of the Binding: The object ViewModel.
Path of the Binding: "MySourceList".

I am not familiar with ExternalProgramsWindowData data but maybe you have to use a ValueConverter in order to make the binding work.

So note that when your viewmodels data is not compatible to your Views data the binding would not work although the binding paths are set correctly.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The list is set as DataContext, so it does not appear as property in the path. Also the concrete inheritance is not necessary at all.